# Cannot open my admin page

Tags: header

I am not able to open my admin page of my site. I am getting this information:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-blog-header.php:14) in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210

How can I fix this?

Comment: As the warning says you have already an output in `wp-blog-header.php`. Have you modified this file?

Comment: No, I haven't modified any thing.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Yeah there is a solution. You modified a file and maybe there is already an output. Like you have a whitespace after closing php tag `?>` for example.

Comment: so what I have to do? and If i have to make any changes then do tell me

Comment: You have to find the unwanted output and remove it. It could be everywhere. Nobody can tell you where to find it. So debugging is the key.
Maybe you installed an extension which cause the problem. But as I wrote, the output could be everywhere.